# Magento2: How to enable Docx, Doc files on wysiwyg to upload attachments to static blocks?

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, file-upload, varien-file-uploader

How I can enable the Docx, Doc or how can I do it on Magento 2 for uploading Docx, Doc attachments to static Blocks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This module makes it possible to upload different filetypes inside the WYSIWYG-editor.*

> *The following filetypes are available by default and it is possible to add extra filetypes to the allowed filetypes in the configuration
>   of the module (General > Content Management > WYSIWYG Options > Extra
>   Allowed Filetypes):*

```
Word (doc, docm, docx)

Excel (csv, xml, xls, xlsx)

PDF (pdf)

Compressed Folder (zip, tar)
```

*https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-WysiwygDownloads*